# HTTP over TCP using Telnet/Hercules/Raw socket/

Tags: http, sockets, tcp

I'm connecting to real-time data on a remote server as a client. I want to send the following to a server and keep the connection open. This is a 'push' protocol.

```
http://server.domain.com:80/protocol/dosomething.txt?POSTDATA=thePostData
```

I can call this in a browser and it's fine. However, if I try to use telnet directly in a windows command prompt, the prompt just exits.

```
  GET protocol/dosomething.txt?POSTDATA=thePostData
```

The same is the case if I use Putty.exe and select Telnet as the protocol. I can't see a way to do this with Hercules at all, as I don't think the server will interpret the GET

Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to match the [HTTP protocol (RFC2616)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) to the letter if you want to use telnet.  Try something like:

```
shell$ telnet www.google.com 80
Trying 173.194.43.50...
Connected to www.google.com (173.194.43.50).
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com:80
Connection: close

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 11 Sep 2012 15:09:51 GMT
...
```

You need to type the following lines including an "empty line" following the "Connection" line.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com:80
Connection: close
```

Comment: Ah.... I forgot, they have local echo turned off by default.  Start with just running `telnet` with no arguments.  Then type `set localecho` and then `open www.google.com 80`.  You should be able to use just about any terminal emulator that understands telnet.

Comment: You should be able to connect a TCP socket to port 80 and send the same text.  Just make sure to terminate lines with a CR-NL pair (`"\r\n"`) and include the empty line following the headers.  Then read the response and close the socket when you are done.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I'm not getting any reply when I send the data. My syntax is incorrect, I think. I'm doing this with Hercules (TCP client): connecting to server.domain.com on 80. I get a 'connected' response. Then I'm sending this: GET\r\n/protocol/dosomething.txt?POSTDATA=thePostData\r\nHTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n I've tried various permutations, but to no avail.I don't even get a response from Google when I send this: `GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n`.